# Mysql trigger not updating table "Cant update table 'users' in stored function/trigger"

Tags: mysql, insert-update, database-trigger

My after insert trigger :

```
UPDATE users
SET users.under_reference = users.under_reference+ 1
WHERE users.username =  new.reference
```

Error :

> Cant update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   aldready used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Change the schema (ref counter in an own table), write a stored procedure or solve it on application side.

Comment: I see what you want. But as the error message says, you can't update the table in the trigger on the same table. Any solution on DB side is too complex compared to just one more query executed from your application.